# How to fix "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException" on pyspark with delta.io and gcs connector jar file

Tags: java, python, scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-storage

I have a simple python file that creates a delta table using the delta python library and a spark session. When I run this file without using google cloud dependencies it works. When I decide to create a delta table on google cloud storage using the gcs hadoop connector and hadoop file system I encounter the error shown in the log.

app.py

```
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from delta import *
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
import json
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession



spark = SparkSession.builder \
            .appName("app") \
            .getOrCreate()

# # schema file
with open('schema.json') as data_file:
  data = data_file.read()

new_schema = StructType.fromJson(json.loads(data))

deltatable = DeltaTable.create(spark) \
            .tableName('table') \
            .addColumns(new_schema) \
            .location("gs://bucket-name/table") \
            .execute() 

df = deltatable.toDF()
print(df.schema)
```

I try to submit this file with spark-submit

```
spark-submit --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:1.0.0,com.google.cloud.bigdataoss:gcs-connector:hadoop3-2.2.1,com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre --conf spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension --conf spark.jars.excludes=javax.jms:jms,com.sun.jdmk:jmxtools,com.sun.jmx:jmxri --conf spark.hadoop.fs.gs.impl=com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem app.py
```

and i get this error

```
  File "/app.py", line 21, in <module>
    deltatable = DeltaTable.create(spark) \
  File "/.ivy2/jars/io.delta_delta-core_2.12-1.0.0.jar/delta/tables.py", line 924, in execute
  File "/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
  File "/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
  File "/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o35.execute.
: org.sparkproject.guava.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2263)
        at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4000)
        at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4789)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.getCachedPlan(SessionCatalog.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FindDataSourceTable.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FindDataSourceTable$$readDataSourceTable(DataSourceStrategy.scala:249)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FindDataSourceTable$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(DataSourceStrategy.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FindDataSourceTable$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(DataSourceStrategy.scala:278)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDown$2(AnalysisHelper.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:74)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDown$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:221)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDown$4(AnalysisHelper.scala:113)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:244)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:406)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:359)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDown$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:113)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:221)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:10
4)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperators(AnalysisHelper.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperators$(AnalysisHelper.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FindDataSourceTable.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:278)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FindDataSourceTable.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:243)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$2(RuleExecutor.scala:216)
        at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:126)
        at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1(RuleExecutor.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1$adapted(RuleExecutor.scala:205)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
at org.aat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$$execute
SameContext(Analyzer.scala:196)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:190)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$executeAndTrack$1(RuleExecutor.scala:183)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.executeAndTrack(RuleExecutor.scala:183)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1(Analyzer.scala:174)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:228)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:173)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$analyzed$1(QueryExecution.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:143)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:143)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:71)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.$anonfun$ofRows$1(Dataset.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.table(DataFrameReader.scala:891)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.table(SparkSession.scala:596)
        at io.delta.tables.DeltaTable$.forName(DeltaTable.scala:619)
        at io.delta.tables.DeltaTable$.forName(DeltaTable.scala:608)
        at io.delta.ta        bles.DeltaTableBuilder.execute(DeltaTableBuilder.scala:362)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:135)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3352)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:479)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:361)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaTableUtils$.findDeltaTableRoot(DeltaTable.scala:164)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.sources.DeltaDataSource$.parsePathIdentifier(DeltaDataSource.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaTableV2.x$1$lzycompute(DeltaTableV2.scala:67)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaTableV2.x$1(DeltaTableV2.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaTableV2.rootPath$lzycompute(DeltaTableV2.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaTableV2.rootPath(DeltaTableV2.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaTableV2.deltaLog$lzycompute(DeltaTableV2.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaTableV2.deltaLog(DeltaTableV2.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaTableV2.toBaseRelation(DeltaTableV2.scala:139)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.sources.DeltaDataSource.createRelation(DeltaDataSource.scala:177)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:360)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FindDataSourceTable.$anonfun$readDataSourceTable$1(DataSourceStrategy.scala:261)
at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4792)
        at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3599)
        at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2379)
        at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2342)
        at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2257)
        ... 72 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        ... 95 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(boolean, java.lang.String, long, long)'
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.cooplock.CooperativeLockingOptions$Builder.build(CooperativeLockingOptions.java:58)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.cooplock.CooperativeLockingOptions.<clinit>(CooperativeLockingOptions.java:33)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemConfiguration.<clinit>(GoogleHadoopFileSystemConfiguration.java:376)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.<init>(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:246)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem.<init>(GoogleHadoopFileSystem.java:58)
        ... 100 more

21/06/18 07:05:36 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://instance.us-central1-a.c.micro-eye-300714.internal:4040
21/06/18 07:05:36 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
21/06/18 07:05:36 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
21/06/18 07:05:36 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
21/06/18 07:05:36 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
21/06/18 07:05:36 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
21/06/18 07:05:36 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
21/06/18 07:05:36 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
21/06/18 07:05:36 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-e2a37bf6-f7a1-49f6-9fe1-e86fcf417b10
21/06/18 07:05:36 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-e2a37bf6-f7a1-49f6-9fe1-e86fcf417b10/pyspark-c954a72f-b482-433e-a934-01326481e44b
21/06/18 07:05:36 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-ed34bc3c-7736-42cf-9d31-e75841b0d214
```

Versions

```
python 3.8
spark 3.1.2 with hadoop 3.2
scala 2.12.0
java 11
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I solve it?

Comment: Have you tried: from delta.tables import *

Comment: Yes. I have, i still got the same error

Comment: Any news on this?